# How to create and use controllers specifically for test?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I want to have my Spring test with context that contains a controller.
This controller is not visible outside the tests and serves only purpose of testing. 
So when i perform request through *mockMvc*, this request reach a controller.

How should i define the controller? I don't want to place it outside test package, because i don't need it there.

Comment: why do you want it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark your controller by the test profile and this bean doesn't instantiate in the production mode:

```
@Profile("test")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apiUrl")
public class TestController {
  ...
}
```

Also, if you use spring boot you can use the `TestConfiguration` immediately in your tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ApiTest {

    @Test
    void testApi() {
        // send request to test API
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {        

        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/apiUrl")
        public class TestController {

            @GetMapping("/test")
            public String test() {
                return "STUB";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I need such a test for my library. This library will be shared between clients. Clients use spring , and I'm concerned whether solution you proroposed would affect clients code ?(if they defined their own test profile) what I mean is if they occasionally meet the controller in they test. How to prevent controller exposure